# install perl script as windows service

Tags: windows, perl, service

I am trying to get a Perl script to install as a Windows service. The Perl code for the purpose of experimentation is very simple (see below)

```
my $num = 1;

while( $num == 1 )
{
    open(FH, ">>", "C:\\Perl\\MyCode\\Service\\svclog.txt");
    print FH "hello world\n";
    close(FH);
    sleep 3;
}
```

I have been trying to install the script using the native Windows SC commands...

```
SC CREATE MyPerlService binpath= "C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe C:\Perl\MyCode\Service\perlsvc.pl" error= normal start= auto DisplayName= "My Perl Service" type= own
```

The service installs fine. BUT I try to start it up and get a message telling me the service failed to start in the allocated time.

It goes without saying that I know very little about Windows services. 
I suspect that Windows is waiting for a start() type function to execute but I'm just guessing here. Having said that I'd kind of expect Windows to check/cater for that when it installs the service ??? Dunno :)

I can't use any 3rd party products really, as this is internal to work and there is a whole software ordering process that takes months and months. Ideally I need something that I could use/write that comes with native Windows XP/2003 or Perl 5.8.8 (old versions - yes)

If anyone can point me in the direction of an example of a  Perl (or DOS) script that has been installed as a windows service and the code that installed it - I would be very grateful.

for info - I've scoured the Web and a lot of people are talking about using **INSTSRV** and **SRVANY** or the **PDK** - All of which I have no access to at the moment.

Thank you

Trevor

Comment: A Google search turns up a few possible solutions, such as [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=435700), which uses the `Win32:Daemon` package.

Comment: Thanks David, I came across that too and my Perl installation didn't have Win32::Daemon installed - unless I missed something (entirely possible)
I may look at that module more closely as getting Perl modules installed is a little easier than purchasing/installing 3rd party apps.

Comment: @thonnor If it's not installed... install it :-)

Comment: I ended up going down the INSTSRV.exe/SRVANY.exe route in the end. I came across a very helpful chap at work who has sped up the whole process of 3rd party software being used.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, SRVANY is pretty limited.  It can't stop the service, for example.  I'd recommend looking at [nssm](http://nssm.cc).  I have a cpan module that makes it easier to use called [Win32::ServiceManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ServiceManager).